# iOS 11 CoreBluetooth: Cannot remove an observer CBPeripheral for the key path "delegate"

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Ever since iOS 11 was released, I'm experiencing an esporadic but frequent crash with the following signature:

```
Cannot remove an observer <CBPeripheral 0x1c010ef10> for the key path "delegate" from <CBPeripheral 0x1c010ef10> because it is not registered as an observer.
```

This happens in the context of a scan for Bluetooth devices, a later connection to one of them and a final cleanup of the whole process. All these tasks are performed in a non-main dispatch queue to soften the pressure on the main thread (for smoother UI experience). This very code has been running without incident ever since iOS 9 days and only now that iOS 11 came out, started to crash.

The only references I've found in the net so far regarding this behaviour are [this](https://forums.estimote.com/t/estbulkupdater-crashing-app-on-ios-11/7373/3) and [this](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/266) post for the *Estimote SDK*. These references suggest that something might be going on with parallel instances of the **CBCentralManager** in different dispatch queues, however, nothing regarding special care on the matter is stated in the official [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html). Also, a response from an **Apple Staff** member to [another](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84098) **CoreBluetooth** issue stating:

> *iOS 11 is in general going to be less forgiving for apps which don't hold a proper reference to CB objects...*

Doesn't sound very encouraging. I tried profiling the app and looking for potential leaks using XCode and it's companion tools but this didnt't shed much light on it either.

Has anybody else experienced similar issues? Any suggestions on how to workaround it? Ideas on where to dig next?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing since iOS 11, and am just as unsure on the cause or how to solve it. It's also extremely hard to recreate.

Comment: In a private exchange with an Apple employee, he suggests to handle all CBCentral activities in the same thread, due to signalling of callbacks and other messaging events towards objects. Apparently, if resulting objects such as _CBPeripheral_ are handled and released in other threads, the mentioned signalling might refer to a released object and hence, crash.

No definitive conclusions on this yet though.

Comment: I had also come to the same conclusion individually, as a result of trial and error, but I didn't want to write here until I confirmed this fixed it. This piece of knowledge should be published in a more searchable way. It seems at least everything related to scanning, or includes fast retain and release of peripherals should be handled in the same thread.Thank you for confirming though! it should really be in the documentation.

Comment: So, what is exactly the solution with this then? Can someone make a proper answer to the question? It would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing period, in our particular case the solution consisted in translating all the Bluetooth stack related work to the *mainQueue*. Meaning that all the related callbacks exists within Main-thread territory.

This solution requires extra caution with the work performed in those callbacks (UI runs here too), but since most **CoreBluetooth** actions are asynchronous by default, this has proven feasible. This workaround has been confirmed in iOS 11 and so far no issues have been reported in iOS 12 as well.

The takeaway here is: Handle ***ONLY*** the absolutely necessary bits in *mainQueue*, and then transfer the rest of the load elsewhere if necessary.